# Open/Closed Serial Ports vs Permissions Denied Pyserial

Tags: python, serial-port, port, pyserial

I am hoping someone can shed some light between the difference of a closed/open serial port and getting the permissions of a serial port? Specifically with pyserial. Currently, I feel like they are one of the same.

I will try to illustrate my question by using pyserial.
Let say I am trying to talk to a microcontroller using uart and I have a serial port open on a windows pc to talk to it. Running code with pyserial everything works fine as expected.

However lets say I am using realterm to use the serial port to read data on the line.

Now if I run the python code again, I will get a permission error from pyserial indicating it is not available. It is **NOT** saying the serial port is currently open.

The reason why I am making the distinction between the two is in my code with pyserial, I am detecting if the serial port is open or not. If the serial port is open, use the serial port. If not, do not use it.

Here is some code I am using currently to check and open a serial port (using python/pyserial):

```
    def open_port(self):
# Checking if the port is already open or not. If it is not open, lets open it.
        if(self.isOpen() == False):  # NOTE This check will not goes as I expect if another program has opened it. Shouldn't this check determine if the resource is available to be used?
            try:
                self.open()
            except serial.SerialException as e:
                print(e) # Printing the raw message.
                error_message = "The port you are trying to open ("+str(self.port)+")"+" is currently open." # My own message. This might be wrong based on this discussion.
                print(error_message)
                sys.exit()
            else:
                ...   # Do other things
```

Normally this code works fine without any issues.

However, here is the output of the same code if another program (realterm) is using the serial port or if I am using another instance of pyserial with the same serial port:

```
could not open port 'COM4': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)
The port you are trying to open (COM4) is currently open.
```

As you can see here it could not use the serial port (which makes sense because I am using realterm.)
What I am confused though is that shouldn't `if(self.isOpen() == False):` check if the serial port is available to be used?

I thought a serial port being open or closed is equivalent to saying the resource is being used or not. Where if the serial port is open it is being used by a application and other applications should not touch it.

However the raw error indicates there is a permission error with the serial port.
Is there a difference between opening and closing a port and the permissions of the port? I thought they were essentially the same?

If they are different can some please explain the differences between them? Also how can I in pyserial determine if a serial resource can be used?

Thank you for your help and please let me know if you have any more questions!

Comment: Is this article helpful? [CreateFile not able to share serial (COM) port](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50215937/9014308)

Comment: There is definitely a difference if the OS is Linux/UNIX.

Comment: Unfortunately @kunif it did not get me any closer to my solution. Thanks for the article though!

Comment: @sawdust I am currently using windows. However I would be curious what is the difference in linux/Unix. It might build some intuition.